# why won't the added email address display in the messageBox?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have an html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\fz3temp-1\email picker.css"> 
<script src="email picker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">

        <form>
        <h4>Enter the email addresses in the input box below</h4>
            email:<input id="emailIn" type="text" placeholder=" email" />
            <input type="submit" value="Show entry" onsubmit="insert()" />
        </form>

        <div id="display"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and a javascript file:

```
    var entries = [];
    var emailInput = document.getElementById("emailIn");
    var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

    function insert() {
        entries.push(emailInput.value);
        clearAndShow();
    };

    function clearAndShow() {

    emailInput.value = "";
    messageBox.innerHTML = "";

      messageBox.innerHTML += "Emails: " + entries.join(", ") + "<br/>";
    };
```

and a simple .css file.

When I run the code in my browser the last email input does not display. 
What am I missing? 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `onsubmit` is an attribute of a `<form>` not an `<input>`

Comment: Do you really have a space in the name of your js file ?

Comment: Do you have errors in the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) ? Is the js file loaded ?

Comment: When I used submit and onsubmit you could tell that the .js file had loaded because it performed part of the function correctly. That being the clearing of the emailInput.value "". Using an input button and onclick nothing happens at all. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you submit the form and so the page is reset (and you don't bind the `insert` function anyway as an input doesn't receive the `submit` event).

You may replace

```
        <input type="submit" value="Show entry" onsubmit="insert()" />
```

with

```
        <input type="button" value="Show entry" onclick="insert()" />
```

Comment: Tried this before and didn't work for me. I think it might be something to do with localhost and my XAMPP setup.